# Sylius and Promotions

Tags: sylius

When adding a promotion you can choose that if cart contains a product you can apply a discount to items in cart.

This way, if you have 5 products in cart and one of them is selected in the rule configuration, all 5 products in cart will have a discounted price.

My question is if this can be modified so only those products selected in the rule will have the discount and not every product you have in cart.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

The concept of promotions in *Sylius* is based on 3 pillars: rules, actions and filters.

- rules specify in which case promotion will be applied (in your case it when order contains a specific product) - so they have **nothing** in common with a discount applied
- actions are about what discount is applied - which means how many money/how big percentage of money will be cut of the final price of order/item
- filters are about on which items discount will be applied (so they're strictly connected with item-based actions)

So in your case you should specify "Contains product" rule, then add a "Item fixed/percentage discount" action. And if you want to apply discount only on specific product - you must configure "Product filter" with it.
I know it can be a little bit confusing at the first time, but if you think about it's quite good separation of responsibility.
So one more time:

- rule - when to apply promotion
- action - how big discount is
- filter - on which items it's applied

Hope it helped ;)